# Is it possible to create an Ad-Hoc wireless network that is only visible to specific devices?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, iphone, ad-hoc-network

I want to create an ad-hoc wireless network on my laptop, but I only want my iPhone to be able to connect to it. I know you can set a password etc. but I'd prefer it if it just wasn't publicly visible.

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit.

Any pointers on this would be appreciated. Even if it's just to tell me it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

can you set the ssid to not be visible ? This will mean you need to know the name of the network to connect. Its no form of security though.

Comment: +1 for no form of security. Some devices may be unable to see it, but anyone with a GNU/Linux system will see it without any problems just by just using standard utilities.

Comment: I cannot see any option to hide the SSID during the creation wizard. Thanks for the suggestion. Is there maybe a way of doing this after creation through command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Don't broadcast it is the obvious first thing to do, but as stated, anyone with some tools will be able to find it.

The other thing worth saying, is that you should turn it off when not in use.